# Return authenticated users favorites list with twitter gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, twitter, twitter-gem

I'm looking at creating a project where I would like a user to login and then it will return all their tweets from a specific time duration.

I have seen that it is possible using the twitter Api, but as I'm planning to use the twitter gem I would of assumed it can do this as well. However, when I look at the docs for favorite they seem to just be writing actions not reading.

I noticed there there is a method called `Twitter.mentions_timeline` but can't find it anywhere in the docs. I'm wondering if there would be a similar one for `Twitter.favorites_timeline` but can't find anything in the docs.

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a call `Twitter.favorites`. It's not a timeline but that should contain the data you need.

See [how the twitter gem is doing it](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/api/favorites.rb) and the [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list).

Comment: Ah yeah that's great thanks. Is it possible to check if the results can be filtered if the tweet content is containing a URL.

Comment: You would most probably have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Could it be possible to do a conditional checking the `entities url` has text in it.

Comment: Yes. But you won't get it from the API.

Comment: But I thought the entities property was in the json for each returned so I could just filter it from there?

Comment: Exactly. You have to do it by yourself.